# How to prevent question mark in diamond shape from showing up?

Tags: php, html, character-encoding

I searched through StackOverFlow and found similar questions but nothing that answered my particular situation so I thought of asking this as a new question.

When i insert entries into the database form a textbox, i use mysql_real_escape_string(); and then when i display the information i use htmlspecialchars();

I use UTF-8 as the charset.  We are using HTML5  formatting.  The collation for the database was by default set to latin1_swedish_ci, so i used that. For all the tables its set to latin1_swedish_ci. For all the fields in the table we use utf8_general_ci.

As an example, this is how it looks when its shown:

```
   �Who are you?� he asked his iPhone. �I am a humble 
   personal assistant,� the device replied, bringing the biggest...
```

How do i fix this?

Comment: Are you able to change the character set of your database? Make it UTF-8 also if you can - it saves a _lot_ of hassle. Otherwise, if you are storing special characters in your database that can be represented in latin1_swedish then you will need to convert them to UTF-8 before displaying. And, when inserting data, you'll need to convert from UTF-8 back to latin1 - which is why it is easier to make everything the same charset.

Comment: You're inserting Unicode data to a Latin1 database. Either convert the database to Unicode or convert the data to Latin1 before inserting it.

Comment: Be sure that your files also has utf-8 encoding

Comment: The combination of the 3 previous comments is the right answer. =P

Comment: Use mysql_set_charset as well. Make sure your files are utf-8 encoded and without BOM. Set the fields, the table and the db itself to utf-8 encoding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is the collation setting, make sure it is one of the utf8 ones (like utf8_general_ci) for database, tables and text fields.

Furthermore make sure that you are setting your connection charset to UTF-8 as well :

```
SET NAMES utf8;
```

Comment: The fields in the tables use utf8_general_ci.

Comment: Use the same utf8 collation for the database and tables as well. Updated my answer

Comment: Ah, if all the fields are UTF-8 then (afaik) the table and database collations won't have an effect (except to define a default collation for new tables/columns that are added without their own collation). So it will be the connection string, as @ilanco says.

Comment: @ariel just execute the query before doing anything else, although I recommend using PDO and not worry about it. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php